# Problem with drawing multiple lines using matplotlib with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python and trying to create a plot with one y variable and two x variables. I want the two lines to show up in the same plot with different labels and colors/makrers. Here is my code to attempt:

```
y = lambda x: x**(-3)
z = lambda x: x**(-10)
x_grid = np.linspace(1,10, 10)
v_y = []
v_z = []

for i in x_grid:
  vy=y(i)
  v_y.append(vy)
v_y_array = np.array(v_y)

for j in x_grid:
  vz=y(j)
  v_z.append(vz)
v_z_array = np.array(v_z)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

line1, = ax.plot(x_grid, v_y_array, 'b--', label='function 1')
line2, = ax.plot(x_grid, v_z_array, 'r--', label='function 1')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

However, the figure only shows the second line and ignores the first.

But if I try to do the following, it works out fine.

```
y = lambda x: x**(-3)
z = lambda x: x**(-10)
x_grid = np.linspace(1,10, 10)
v_y = []
v_z = []

for i in x_grid:
  vy=y(i)
  v_y.append(vy)
v_y_array = np.array(v_y)

for j in x_grid:
  vz=y(j)
  v_z.append(vz)
v_z_array = np.array(v_z)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x_grid,v_y_array,'r--', v_z_array, 'b--', label='x**(-3) function')
ax.set_title('Two Functions')
ax.legend(['x**(-3) function','x**(-10) function'])

plt.show()
```

I wonder what was the problem with my first set of codes that won't produce the figure that I want?

Comment: You've got a typo in the for loop. You use the lambda function `y` to set values for both `vy` and `vz`.

Comment: Both do exactly the same, except that in the second code, the blue plot uses x values `from 1 to 10` while the first code uses x values `from 0 to 9` for both plots thus they overlap making the second one only visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the **red** and **blue** lines don't overlap in the second plot lies [in the official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

```
ax.plot(x_grid, v_y_array,'r--', v_z_array, 'b--', label='x**(-3) function')
```

The first set of three arguments `x_grid, v_y_array,'r--', v_z_array,` follows this pattern:

> plot(x, y, 'bo')  # plot x and y using blue circle markers

The second set has only two arguments: `v_z_array, 'b--',` and follow this pattern:

> plot(y)           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1

> plot(y, 'r+')     # ditto, but with red plusses

Thus, the second set is infering a sequence of x values that equals `range(0, 10)`(values from 0 to 9 inclusive), while the first set of arguments uses `x_grid`which equals `range(1, 11)` (values from 1 to 10 inclusive).

[image: Non overlapping plots]